# XML Parsing in Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I've tried a few things, but I'm new to parsing XML files and can't seem to get anything to work. Below is an example XML file I need to parse through, but the section shown is repeated 1000s of times over. I need to read the script and identity each `Name="TaskName"` for every task that contains `NewFilesOnly="1"` in the Source.

```
<Task ID="1234" Name="TaskName" Active="1">     
    <Source HostID="servername1" Type="Share" Path="" FileMask="Filename.csv" DeleteOrig="1" NewFilesOnly="1" SearchSubdirs="0" Unzip="0" RetryIfNoFiles="0" UseDefRetryCount="1" UseDefRetryTimeoutSecs="1" UseDefDelOldStateDays="1" UseDefStateCaching="1" UseDefRescanSecs="1" UDMxFi="1" UDMxBy="1" UseDefWinCopyFileAPI="1" ID="11"/>
    <Destination HostID="servername2" Type="Share" Path="Incoming" FileName="[OrigName]" UseOrigName="1" ForceDir="1" OverwriteOrig="1" UseRelativeSubdirs="1" Zip="0" UseDefRetryCount="1" UseDefRetryTimeoutSecs="1" UseDefWinCopyFileAPI="1" ID="12"/>
    <NextActions>
        <NextAction DoIfSuccess="0" DoIfFailure="1" DoIfNoAction="0" DoAfter="Task" Type="Email" HostID="12345" AddressTo="somebody@west.com" Subject="Subject" Message="Message"/>
    </NextActions>
</Task>
```

I understand the code below isn't valid, but it helps demonstrate the logic that I'm trying to accomplish.

```
$XML = [xml] (Get-Content C:\files\export.xml)
$SearchString = "*NewFilesOnly=*"

foreach ($Task in <TASK>){
Select-String $SearchString
Write-Host $Task
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an XML file (say, `test.xml`) like this:

```
<Tasks>
    <Task ID="1234" Name="TaskName1" Active="1">     
        <Source HostID="servername1" Type="Share" Path="" FileMask="Filename.csv" DeleteOrig="1" NewFilesOnly="1" SearchSubdirs="0" Unzip="0" RetryIfNoFiles="0" UseDefRetryCount="1" UseDefRetryTimeoutSecs="1" UseDefDelOldStateDays="1" UseDefStateCaching="1" UseDefRescanSecs="1" UDMxFi="1" UDMxBy="1" UseDefWinCopyFileAPI="1" ID="11"/>
        <Destination HostID="servername2" Type="Share" Path="Incoming" FileName="[OrigName]" UseOrigName="1" ForceDir="1" OverwriteOrig="1" UseRelativeSubdirs="1" Zip="0" UseDefRetryCount="1" UseDefRetryTimeoutSecs="1" UseDefWinCopyFileAPI="1" ID="12"/>
        <NextActions>
            <NextAction DoIfSuccess="0" DoIfFailure="1" DoIfNoAction="0" DoAfter="Task" Type="Email" HostID="12345" AddressTo="somebody@west.com" Subject="Subject" Message="Message"/>
        </NextActions>
    </Task>
    <Task ID="1235" Name="TaskName2" Active="1">     
        <Source HostID="servername1" Type="Share" Path="" FileMask="Filename.csv" DeleteOrig="1" NewFilesOnly="0" SearchSubdirs="0" Unzip="0" RetryIfNoFiles="0" UseDefRetryCount="1" UseDefRetryTimeoutSecs="1" UseDefDelOldStateDays="1" UseDefStateCaching="1" UseDefRescanSecs="1" UDMxFi="1" UDMxBy="1" UseDefWinCopyFileAPI="1" ID="11"/>
        <Destination HostID="servername2" Type="Share" Path="Incoming" FileName="[OrigName]" UseOrigName="1" ForceDir="1" OverwriteOrig="1" UseRelativeSubdirs="1" Zip="0" UseDefRetryCount="1" UseDefRetryTimeoutSecs="1" UseDefWinCopyFileAPI="1" ID="12"/>
        <NextActions>
            <NextAction DoIfSuccess="0" DoIfFailure="1" DoIfNoAction="0" DoAfter="Task" Type="Email" HostID="12345" AddressTo="somebody@west.com" Subject="Subject" Message="Message"/>
        </NextActions>
    </Task>
    <Task ID="1236" Name="TaskName3" Active="1">     
        <Source HostID="servername1" Type="Share" Path="" FileMask="Filename.csv" DeleteOrig="1" NewFilesOnly="1" SearchSubdirs="0" Unzip="0" RetryIfNoFiles="0" UseDefRetryCount="1" UseDefRetryTimeoutSecs="1" UseDefDelOldStateDays="1" UseDefStateCaching="1" UseDefRescanSecs="1" UDMxFi="1" UDMxBy="1" UseDefWinCopyFileAPI="1" ID="11"/>
        <Destination HostID="servername2" Type="Share" Path="Incoming" FileName="[OrigName]" UseOrigName="1" ForceDir="1" OverwriteOrig="1" UseRelativeSubdirs="1" Zip="0" UseDefRetryCount="1" UseDefRetryTimeoutSecs="1" UseDefWinCopyFileAPI="1" ID="12"/>
        <NextActions>
            <NextAction DoIfSuccess="0" DoIfFailure="1" DoIfNoAction="0" DoAfter="Task" Type="Email" HostID="12345" AddressTo="somebody@west.com" Subject="Subject" Message="Message"/>
        </NextActions>
    </Task>
</Tasks>
```

One option is to do this:

```
[xml]$xmlDoc = Get-Content .\test.xml
$xmlDoc.Tasks.Task | Where-Object {$_.Source.NewFilesOnly -eq '1'}
```

Which produces this output:

```
ID          : 1234
Name        : TaskName1
Active      : 1
Source      : Source
Destination : Destination
NextActions : NextActions

ID          : 1236
Name        : TaskName3
Active      : 1
Source      : Source
Destination : Destination
NextActions : NextActions
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it, is to use `Select-XML` with a XPath expression. If the size of the data you are processing is very large, you might get a better performance with this approach compared to `Get-Content` and type casting to xml.

```bsh
$selectXmlSplat = @{
    'Path' = 'C:\Users\ps894840\Desktop\miccfg-export.xml'
    'XPath' = '//Source[@NewFilesOnly="1"]//ancestor::Task'
}
Select-Xml @selectXmlSplat | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Node
```

Answer (score 0):

After much digging I finally go it to work!

```
[XML]$XMLALL = Get-Content "C:\file\export.xml" 
$Tasks = $XMLALL.Exported.Tasks.Task

    Foreach ($item in $Tasks){

        $Name = $item.Name
        $NFO = $item.Source.NewFilesOnly

        Write-Host $Name
        Write-Host $NFO

    }
```